# Flow JS isnt finding errors in JSX blocks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flowtype

I have the following component which I have added flow typing markup to:

```
// @flow                                          
                                                            
import * as React from 'react';                             
                                                  
type UnauthorisedProps = {|                       
  message :string                                                  
|};                                                                       
                                                                          
export function Unauthorised(props :UnauthorisedProps) :* {               
  return (                                                               
    <div>                                                                 
      <div>{ props.message }</div>                                        
    </div>                                           
  );                                            
}
```

But in the place this is used, flow isn't catching this error:

```
import { Unauthorised } from '../unauthorised/Unauthorised';
// @flow

function SomethingElse(props) {
    return (<Unauthorised mexssage={ props.message } );
}
```

I am running the command

```
yarn run flow check
```

and it isn't reporting the obvious error that `mexssage` is mispelled.

If I change the `UnauthorisedProps` definition to something invalid, flow does report an error so it is looking at the code.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few causes / missing steps in my initial setup.

1. `.flowConfig` needed this automatic value:

   [lints]

   [options]

   +react.runtime=automatic
2. The import of React needed to change from `import React from 'react';` to

   import * as React from 'react';
3. The return type of the function needed to: `React.Node`

Then it worked.